# What is the easiest way to upload and retrieve images from MySQL database using JSP?

Tags: html, mysql, database, image, web

I want to know what is the best and easiest way to upload and retrieve images from MySQL database.Is there anything other than using BLOB? Any frameworks would be ok. Would appreciate if a link to a good tutorial is posted.

Comment: Its like asking with car is best? wich one should i buy..

Comment: Storing images in BLOB columns is how you create a monster you can never slay. Use a filesystem or object store, either self-hosted or like Amazon S3.